# Como evitar a reinicialização dos elementos da tela ao virar o celular?

Tags: android

Tenho uma Activity com apenas um cronômetro basicamente, e, ao virar o celular, o cronometro é zerado.

Existe algum evento que faz com que a Activity seja reiniciada ao fazer isso? Gostaria de impedir esse comportamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## O problema

Quando você muda a orientação do aparelho, o Android destrói e recria a `Activity`. O que está acontecendo é que você provavelmente está iniciando o seu cronômetro no `onCreate`. Como o `onCreate` está sendo chamado de novo, o estado o seu cronômetro está sendo reiniciado.

O que você deve fazer vai solucionar não apenas o problema da rotação mas o problema de quando sua Activity é destruída em segundo plano porque o sistema precisou de memória (você pode simular essa situação habilitando "Não manter atividades" nas configurações de desenvolvedor do aparelho)

Imagino que seu código seja mais ou menos assim:

```
public class CronometroActivity extends Activity  {
    // ...
    // campos da sua classe
    // ...
    private Cronometro meuCronometro;
    // ...        
    // mais campos da sua classe
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        // inicialização dos elementos da tela
        // ...

        this.meuCronometro = new Cronometro();
        atualizarCronometroDaTela();

    }

    // demais métodos

}
```

Talvez você não tenha uma classe Cronometro e sim outras variáveis mais simples para compor o estado do cronômetro, mas o princípio é o mesmo.

## Solução

Você deverá sobrepor o método `onSaveInstanceState` da `Activity`, que é chamado quando a Activity é destruída pelo sistema. O sistema envia a esse método um `Bundle`, chamado aqui de `estadoDeSaida`, dentro do qual você colocará os dados que quer persistir entre reinicializações da tela. Como você talvez já sabe, um `Bundle` aceita dados dos tipos primitivos do Java, `String`s, objetos `Serializable` e objetos `Parcelable` (dentre alguns outros).
Presumindo aqui que a classe `Cronometro` implementa `Parcelable`, o código ficaria assim:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estadoDeSaida) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(estadoDeSaida);
    estadoDeSaida.putParcelable("chaveDoMeuCronometro", meuCronometro);
}
```

Após a recriação, o `onCreate` será chamado, e será passado para ele esse mesmo `Bundle` no parâmetro `savedInstanceState`, em vez de `null` que fica lá quando a `Activity` está iniciando normalmente. A partir dele, você deverá retirar os dados que havia colocado e recriar o seu cronômetro.

Nesse exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    // inicialização dos elementos da tela
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState) {
        this.meuCronometro = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("chaveDoMeuCronometro")
    } else {
        this.meuCronometro = new Cronometro();
    }

    atualizarCronometroDaTela();
}
```

Dessa forma, sua `Activity` está protegida da perda dessa informação e seu cronômetro não vai zerar.

Entretanto, no caso específico do cronômetro, talvez você precise de uma solução mais engenhosa para evitar a perda de segundos nos quais o cronômetro ficaria congelado, esperando a destruição e recriação. Essa solução é para o caso mais simples (e mais comum) no qual isso não é importante.

Comment: Falta acrescentar que a classe *Cronometro* tem de implementar *Parcelable*. No entanto a solução mais simples seria guardar o estado em milissegundos do cronómetro e o *time* actual. Ao ser recriada a Activity, recria-se o cronómetro com um estado igual à soma do estado gravado com a diferença entre o *time* actual e o *time* guardado, assim evita-se implementar Parceable e resolve-se o problema da paragem do cronómetro.

Comment: @ramaral Eu cheguei a dizer "presumindo que Cronometro implementa Parcelable". :) Não quis entrar em detalhes de como fazer isso porque seria assunto pra outra pergunta. E é muito interessante a sua ideia de solução. Simples o bastante, mesmo dando um bom resultado.

Comment: Tem razão, peço desculpa, não me apercebi dessa frase.

Comment: Sem problema. :)

Comment: Uma nota mais em relação à minha solução: não faz sentido passar classes com comportamento entre *activities*, o que deve ser passado é o seu estado para, a partir dele, recriar a nova instância.

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Do jeito que você falou, eu entendi que você estava passando dois _timestamps_, algo como dois longs.

Comment: Mas depois você falou como se estivesse deixando de recomendar a solução que deu. Ou entendi errado?

Comment: O que quero dizer é que não se deve passar o "objecto cronómetro" mas sim o seu **estado** (valor marcado no mostrador).

Comment: Na minha cabeça, `Cronometro` é um objeto que contém apenas os dados. De qualquer forma, possui algum recurso de referência sobre esse princípio que você mencionou?

Comment: Eu via *Cronometro* também com comportamento, tipo: `start()`, `stop()`, `reset()` etc. Por que passar(neste caso) a classe toda se só é necessário um valor?

Comment: Compreendo que não faz sentido passar objetos que sejam donos de recursos como _streams_ e conexões de rede, mas em casos como o do cronômetro que tenha esses métodos aí que você citou, não vejo mal. Talvez eu não esteja enxergando além desse exemplo, por isso pedi uma referência a esse princípio. Com outros exemplos talvez eu compreenda melhor.

Comment: É claro que num exemplo simples como este pouca importância tem. Suponha que a Activity representa uma corrida de carros, além do cronómetro teria de passar a lista de carros. Tanto *Cronometro* como *Carro* teriam de implementar *Parcelable*. O que eu digo é que é melhor apenas passar o **estado da corrida**. Uma classe que implemente *Parcelable* e que represente esse **estado**, por ex: valor do cronómetro e posição dos carros. Pense em outras situações em que possa haver um número maior de classes envolvidas. Em relação a uma referência: não sei se existe.

Comment: Certo. Acho que entendi o conselho. Vou manter isso em mente. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ótima solução Pablo Almeida, usei esta mesma, com um objeto Serializable, assim não precisei implementar nada do Parceable.
Mas tem que fazer o cast do objeto no retorno do onCreate...

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estadoDeSaida) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(estadoDeSaida);
    estadoDeSaida.putSerializable("chaveDoMeuCronometro", meuCronometro);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    // inicialização dos elementos da tela
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState) {
        this.meuCronometro = (Cronometro) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("chaveDoMeuCronometro")
    } else {
        this.meuCronometro = new Cronometro();
    }

    atualizarCronometroDaTela();
}
```