# Erro ao rotacionar a tela com fragmente 'em aberto'

Tags: java, android

Estou usando o modelo simples de fragment. Existe um que é a **Lista**, e outro **Visualizador** . 
**FragmentActivity** :

```
    if(pFragVisualizar==null){
        pFragVisualizar = new FragVisualizar();
        pFragVisualizar.configuraVisualizador(dados);
    }
    if (!isPortrait()) {
        fragVisualizar = (FragVisualizar) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("visualizar");
        fragVisualizar.configuraVisualizador(dados);
    }
```

**Fragment** :

```
public class FragVisualizar extends Fragment{

protected Dados dados;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate( ((ActCadastro) getActivity()).visualizarID, container, false);
}

public void configuraVisualizador(Dados dados){
    this.dados= dados;
    if(getView()!=null) {
        dados.layout = getView().findViewById(R.id.cadastro_layout_principal);
        dados.atualizarViews();
        dados.restaurarEstado();
    }
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if(dados!=null) {
        dados.layout = view.findViewById(R.id.cadastro_layout_principal);
        dados.atualizarViews();
        dados.restaurarEstado();
    }
}
```

}

Quando um item é selecionado na lista, ele exibe o **pFragVisualizar**  caso esteja na Vertical, ou apenas muda o conteudo do **fragVisualizar** , caso esteja na horizontal. E transmite uma instancia de Dados que coloca os valores nas views. Na vertical o onCreateView acontece depois de configuraVisualizador, ja na horizontal ocorre o contrário.

O problema , é que se o **pFragVisualizar** estiver visível , e a orientação for mudada, ele lança uma exceção *muito* estranha e não está me ajudando a resolver o erro:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{minhaClasse}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment 'minhaClasse' did not create a view.
```

E ainda pior, depois de debugar descobri que o onCreateView ocorre e a view e criada normalmente , embora o erro seja mostrado antes.

Comment: Veja se existe algum erro no *xml* dessa *view*.

Comment: O xml esta funcionando esse erro nao tem nada haver!!! Ja que funciona normalmente, so não funciona nessa situação especifica.

Comment: Da uma debugada, porque quando você gira a tela ele vai recomeçar toda a activity, veja se existe algo nulo na activity ou no fragment iniciado, ou algum problema nos objetos na hora de inflar esse seu fragment, da uma olhada também nessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117178/7461)

Comment: ele da erro na hora de inflar , mas se eu ja abrir em landscape nao da erro, entra normal